# Convert LONG into VARCHAR2 or some text datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, long-integer, type-conversion

As we all know LONG is deprecated in Oracle a long back but Oracle itself is still using this datatype in their views.

So if I have to change LONG into some kind of text datatype how can I achieve that.

I am trying to query this and getting error.

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG
```

Query -

```
SELECT NVL(ie.column_expression, ic.column_name)
from user_ind_columns ic left join user_ind_expressions ie  on ic.index_name = ie.index_name and ic.table_name = ie.table_name 
where ic.table_name = 'Some Table'
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods, one such is `create table` using `TO_LOB`. It is designed to convert a LONG or LONG RAW column to a CLOB or BLOB, respectively. Other methods are using `PL/SQL`, `DBMS_XMLGEN`. You can also use `TO_LOB` in insert statements.

Let's see how to convert `LONG` into `CLOB`-

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (x INT, y LONG);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, RPAD('*',9,'!'));

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, RPAD('*',9,'@'));

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, RPAD('*',9,'#'));

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

So, we have table `t` with column y s `LONG` data type.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t1
  2  AS
  3  SELECT * FROM t
  4  /
SELECT * FROM t
       *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

SQL>
```

We can see the LONG restriction.

Let's use `TO_LOB` to convert it into `CLOB`.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t1
  2  AS
  3  SELECT x,
  4         to_lob(y) as y
  5  FROM t
  6  /

Table created.

SQL> desc t1;
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------
 X                                                              NUMBER(38)
 Y                                                              CLOB

SQL>
```

Now you have the same table with the `LONG` column converted to `CLOB`.

Answer (score 1):

this is stupid (as in probably not efficient) but it works for samll lengths of y (ie < 2000 characters)..

```
CREATE TABLE t (x INT, y LONG);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, RPAD('*',9,'!'));

CREATE TABLE t1
AS
SELECT x,
       regexp_substr(SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select y from t where rowid = '''||rowid||''''),'<Y>(.*)</Y>',1,1,'in',1) y
FROM t
/
```

it works by using dbms_xmlgen to generate a clob based on the LONG column.. then substr-ing the value back out.

this only works for small contents of the LONG column.  but that is all i had and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, to list the objects and their sizes (including info on columns used in indexes), and came with this solution:

```
select idx1.table_owner owner, idx1.table_name, idx1.index_name, listagg(nvl(idx1.column_expression,idx1.column_name),',') within group (order by idx1.column_position) column_name
from xmltable(
    '/ROWSET/ROW'
    passing (select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select ic.table_owner, ic.table_name, ic.index_name, ic.column_position, ic.column_name, ie.column_expression
    from all_ind_columns ic
    left outer join dba_ind_expressions ie on ie.table_owner=ic.table_owner and ie.table_name=ic.table_name and ie.index_name=ic.index_name and ie.column_position=ic.column_position') from dual)
    columns index_name varchar2(30) path 'INDEX_NAME'
        , table_owner varchar2(30) path 'TABLE_OWNER'
        , table_name varchar2(30) path 'TABLE_NAME'
        , column_position number path 'COLUMN_POSITION'
        , column_name varchar2(30) path 'COLUMN_NAME'
        , column_expression varchar2(4000) path 'COLUMN_EXPRESSION') idx1
group by idx1.table_owner, idx1.table_name, idx1.index_name
```